# Can't convert a factor to a character vector with rlang

Tags: r, character, rlang

When trying to convert a factor to a character with `as_character()`, I get an error.

```
a = factor(c(1,2))
a %>% as_character()
Error: Can't convert a `factor` object to a character vector
```

The base equivalent works:

```
a %>% as.character()
[1] "1" "2"
```

Why can't I make this simple operation with `as_character`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because using `as_character` performs coercion and not conversion. Whereas, if you had used `as.character`, it would have done type conversion.

You can check the documentation of the `as_character` function by typing ?as_character`. This will give you more details.